# Laravel: ValidationException::withMessages not sending all errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make some validations in Laravel. I have a resource with nested resources, so I need to validate many things at once. I have a `Level`, which is composed of many `Questions`. So In order to validate them, I first validate the `Level`, and then each question one by one.

I use the following method:

```php
public function ValidateDataAgainstModel($data) {
    $book = Level::ValidationBook(); // Or Answer::ValidationBook()
    $validator = Validator::make($data,
        $book['rules'],
        $book['messages']);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $validator->errors();
    }
    return null;
}
```

That method is used in Level and Question, so it is the same. 
Then I group all errors in a single array like this:

```php
$errors = [];
$errors['level'] = $levelError;
$errors['questions'] = $questionsErrors; //$questionErrors is an array of each question errors
```

Then to check that my array is correct I make a `\Log::info($errors)` and get the following result:

```php
[2018-12-12 23:47:12] local.INFO: array (
  'level' => 
  Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::__set_state(array(
     'messages' => 
    array (
      'name' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Se requiere el nombre del nivel',
      ),
    ),
     'format' => ':message',
  )),
  'questions' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::__set_state(array(
       'messages' => 
      array (
        'description' => 
        array (
          0 => 'Se requiere la descripción de la pregunta',
        ),
      ),
       'format' => ':message',
    )),
    1 => 
    Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::__set_state(array(
       'messages' => 
      array (
        'description' => 
        array (
          0 => 'Se requiere la descripción de la pregunta',
        ),
      ),
       'format' => ':message',
    )),
  ),
)
```

As you can see I have two questions with errors. In order to return this to my client, when I do the following

```php
if ( count($errors) > 0 ) {
    throw ValidationException::withMessages($errors);
}
```

But when the data arrives at my client, the question errors are not complete. Instead of getting an index with an array of the questions errors, I only got one question error.

[image: This is the console.log of the errors]

Does anyone know why this is happening? It seems like is grouping the errors in a single one.

Finally, I'm adding the entire method that computes the result:

```php
public function Create($data) {

    // Create array to handle all the nested resources
    $errors = [];

    // Validate that the data array is correct
    $levelErrors = $this->ValidateDataAgainstModel($data);
    if ( !is_null($levelErrors) ) {
        $errors['level'] = $levelErrors;
    }

    $questionsErrors = [];
    foreach($data['questions'] as $questionData) {
        /*
        * We remove the level_id because we are validating the
        * question content
        */
        $validationBook = Question::ValidationBook();
        unset($validationBook['rules']['level_id']);
        $questionErrors = QuestionService::ValidateDataAgainstModel($questionData, $validationBook);
        if ( !is_null($questionErrors) ) {
            $questionsErrors[$questionData['index']] = $questionErrors;
        }
    }
    if ( count($questionsErrors) > 0 ) {
        $errors['questions'] = $questionsErrors;
    }

    if ( count($errors) > 0 ) {
        \Log::info($errors);
        throw ValidationException::withMessages($errors);
    }

    // Create the object
    $result = Level::create($data);
    return $result;
}
```

I don't know if the problem is the `withErrors` method implementation that you can see here [ValidationException Source Code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.php)

Comment: please post the code that computes `$levelError` and `$questionsErrors`

Comment: it seems that you have the same error twice `Se requiere la descripción de la pregunta`, can you try with two different errors please?